# adding a text of line in a new tab open using window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have 1 button onclick that button I would like to open appropriate url (google.com, youtube.com, or any url) using window.open(). Its perfectly working but now I would like to add note in newly open tab.

how should I add some note in new tab opened using window.open(). I can't use alert because there is already 1 alert for another message. and I can't add 2 messages in 1 alert box.

So I would like to know is it possible to add our custom note in new tab opened using window.open().

code:

```
<script>
    var child = window.open(url, '', 'width=1250,height=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=10,top=70');
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. You cannot do anything while `url` has not same domain.

Comment: what kind of note? Can you describe the desired user experience here?

Comment: @Epsilon Okay. thanks for your time. I will search for another option for doing this.

Comment: @deostroll I have to add some note that "after closing this window please provide your feedback."

Comment: This is an odd way to go about it, but if you are dealing with a out-of-domain page and you want an experience like so...then I'd suggest you can try for an iframe based approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering your updated  *"after closing this window please provide your feedback."* version of your question.

I suggest you put the feedback reminder on the page that opens the popup, instead of in the popup window itself. The following code will open the popup, wait for it to close, **then** alert the user to provide feedback:

```
<script>
child =  window.open("http://www.google.com","google","width=800,height=400,top=30,resizable=yes"); 
if ( child ) {
    child.focus();
    window.timerID = window.setInterval(function() {            // check every 2 seconds to see if popup is closed yet
                    if ( child && !child.closed ) {
                        // keep waiting
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(window.timerID);  
                        alert("Now please provide feedback on your Google experience.");
                    }
                }, 2000);
} else {
    alert("Google cannot open because popups are blocked.");
}
</script>
```